# React Native: When I run 'expo start' the Screen shows Error only Header Appears

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo, apollo-client

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrhDc.jpg)

This is what appears when I run my expo start
I cloned the code from bitbucket and then run it.
This error shows:"react native invariant violation: ApolloProvider was not passed a client instance make sure you pass in your client via the 'client' prop"
This is the Code :

```
let client;
        client = new ApolloClient({
            uri: baseUrl,
            cache,
            defaultOptions: { watchQuery: { fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network' } },
            headers: headers,
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error::', error);
    });


const App = () => {
    const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources();
    const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

    if (!isLoadingComplete) {
        return <AppLoading/> ;
    } else {
      return (
        <ApolloProvider client={client} >
            <Provider store = { store } >
              <PersistGate loading = { null }
                persistor = { persistor } >
                <SafeAreaProvider >
                  <RootSiblingParent >
                      <StatusBar/>
                      <Navigation colorScheme = { colorScheme }/>
                  </RootSiblingParent>
                </SafeAreaProvider>
              </PersistGate>
          </Provider>
        </ApolloProvider>
        );
    }
};

export default App;
```

I have tried several ways to solve it but it seems nothing to be working well

Comment: Add some more information please like your code snippets.

Answer (score -1):

Share your expo diagnostic and from next time state your error name specifically. I guess its Issue #866 yet without seeing the diagnostic its hard to pinpoint your fault. If you don't know how to see diagnostic just type 'run expo diagnostics' in your terminal. Happy coding!

Comment: Expo CLI 4.4.7 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10 10.0.19042
    Binaries:
      Node: 15.12.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
      npm: 7.6.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    npmPackages:
      expo: ~40.0.0 => 40.0.1
      react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
      react-dom: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz => 0.63.2
      react-native-web: ~0.13.12 => 0.13.18
    Expo Workflow: managed This is Expo diagnostics.

Comment: And this is the Error:  "react native invariant violation: ApolloProvider was not passed a client instance make sure you pass in your client via the 'client' prop"

Comment: use this.client and check again